# SQL: Update Nulls with Previous Timeframe Values

Tags: sql-server, null, sql-update

I currently have a resulting table in SQL that shows during which time period (college semester) a person's address changed  This doesn't happen every time period, so some rows are showing null as expected  I am needing these to update ("fill down") for each subsequent time period until a new address change is entered

I included these two IDs because they represent the two possible cases of what I am seeing:

-ID 1234 should fill the preceding Terms with the Sequence 1 county (shown here)

-ID 5678 should fill the preceding Terms with the Sequence 1 county as well (CLAY in this case) based on a previously joined table

Currently, I am showing something along the lines of:

```
ID       TERM         COUNTY     SEQUENCE
------------------------------------------
1234     201308       null       null
1234     201401       null       null
1234     201408       ORANGE     1
1234     201501       null       null
1234     201505       null       null
1234     201508       OSCEOLA    3
1234     201601       null       null
5678     201301       null       null
5678     201305       null       null
5678     201308       ST JOHNS   3
5678     201401       null       null
5678     201405       null       null
5678     201408       null       null
5678     201501       null       null
5678     201505       DUVAL      4
```

And I need the output to look like:

```
ID       TERM       COUNTY       SEQUENCE
---------------------------------------------
1234     201308     ORANGE       null
1234     201401     ORANGE       null
1234     201408     ORANGE       1
1234     201501     ORANGE       null
1234     201505     ORANGE       null
1234     201508     OSCEOLA      3
1234     201601     OSCEOLA      null
5678     201301     CLAY         null
5678     201305     CLAY         null
5678     201308     ST JOHNS     3
5678     201401     ST JOHNS     null
5678     201405     ST JOHNS     null
5678     201408     ST JOHNS     null
5678     201501     ST JOHNS     null
5678     201505     DUVAL        4
```

This is my first time coming across an update clause need like this, so any insight you may be able to provide will be greatly appreciated!

*I am not sure how much of the previous code will be relevant, but here is essentially the temp table code that feeds into the final output ("PIDM" is the ID):

```
DROP TABLE #ADDRESS_PT_1--, #ADDRESS_PT_2
GO

SELECT SPRADDR_PIDM 'PIDM', Y.TERM, SPRADDR_SEQNO 'SEQNO', SPRADDR_STAT_CODE 'STATE', SPRADDR_CNTY_CODE 'CNTY', 
BANNR_TERM = CASE
  WHEN Y2.TERM IS NULL THEN Y.TERM
  ELSE Y2.TERM
  END
INTO #ADDRESS_PT_1
FROM SPRADDR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RCACYR Y2
  ON (SPRADDR_ACTIVITY_DATE BETWEEN Y2.BEGIN_DATE AND Y2.END_DATE
      AND SUBSTRING(Y2.TERM,5,2) IN ('50','80','10')),
    RCACYR Y
WHERE SPRADDR_ACTIVITY_DATE BETWEEN Y.BEGIN_DATE AND Y.END_DATE
  AND SUBSTRING(Y.TERM,5,2) IN ('05','08','01')
  AND SPRADDR_ATYP_CODE = 'MA'
ORDER BY SPRADDR_PIDM, SPRADDR_SEQNO
GO

/* Get the individuals addresses for each term */
SELECT *
--INTO #ADDRESS_PT_2
FROM #ADDRESS_PT_1 X
LEFT JOIN RCCNTY C 
    ON C.COUNTY = X.CNTY
WHERE X.SEQNO = (SELECT MAX(A.SEQNO)
                  FROM #ADDRESS_PT_1 A
                  WHERE X.PIDM = A.PIDM
                                        AND X.TERM = A.TERM)
    --AND X.PIDM = 5678
ORDER BY X.PIDM, X.SEQNO
GO
```

The output from this is:

```
PIDM    TERM    SEQNO   STATE   CNTY    BANNR_TERM  COUNTY  COUNTY_TITLE    COUNTY_REGION   COUNTY_REGION_TITLE
5678    201108  1       FL      CLAY    201108      CLAY    CLAY            2               Northeast Florida   
5678    201308  3       FL      ST J    201308      ST J    ST. JOHNS       2               Northeast Florida   
5678    201505  5       FL      DUVA    201550      DUVA    DUVAL           2               Duval County
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thank you very much, Marc. I hunted around for how to do that but didn't see it. I will remember that for the future!

Comment: why Clay for  5678,why not StJohns

Comment: TheGameiswar: The "address change sequence table" is imperfect in a few ways, unfortunately. We are at the mercy of when the students notify us of their address changes, and some are more diligent than others. The 5678 case is one where we had a previous address before the student started (CLAY county), and the 1234 is one where we didn't have the address until after (using the Sequence 1 of ORANGE county as a matter of practice).

Comment: @AdamD So, you got this output - what you want next? The output from your query is a little bit... other than in first part of question

Comment: @gofr The code and output I edited in is for a temp table earlier in the code that feeds the final output (the first part of my initial post). The code you provided definitely works for ID (PIDM) 5678 since that person's Sequence 1 county is "CLAY". The Sequence 1 county will not always be "CLAY", however, and the full list of students for this query is many thousand individual IDs. 

In the code you posted, is there a way to change the 'CLAY' in your coalesce clause (the case, when, then portion) to reflect whatever the student's Sequence 1 county is (might be CLAY, might not be)?

Comment: @AdamD yeah, I see it, thanks. I understand that you need put last COUNTY instead of NULLs in your result-set. To get this you need to JOIN (OUTER APPLY) your result-set with main table to get LAST row with NOT NULL value. In my answer I used NEXT (alias `p`) value and PREV (alias `p1`) because there was no NOT NULL rows for ID `1234` and `5678` in sample you provided.

Comment: I add some explanation to my answer, please, try to implement it.

Comment: @gofr1 OK, we are getting closer. From my full data, I have the same output you have which is great. The only missing piece now is the NULL values showing for ID 5678 in TERMs 201301 and 201305. Rather than NULL, I need those to show the COUNTY ('CLAY') from the bottom output of my main post, for PIDM 5678 and TERM 201108 which is Sequence Number 1. Thoughts?

Comment: How about taking the result you just found, then adding one more UPDATE after to find the instances where that column is now NULL, and updating those to reflect the Sequence 1 values? I'll try that now! (My new father brain works much better in the morning! HAH!)

Comment: @AdamD I advice you to add OUTER APPLY with table that HAS rows with SEQUENCE=1 for that ID's, or if there are no such rows you van add `,'CLAY'` to COALESCE

Comment: Finished! Many thanks again, @gofr1 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put in CTE the sample you provided. Then I OUTER APPLY (`p`) previous row with NOT NULL `COUNTY`, and another OUTER APPLY that gets the row with `[SEQUENCE] = 1` for each `ID`. Instead of `FROM cte` in last OUTER APPLY use table (`FROM SPRADDR`) that have rows with `[SEQUENCE] = 1` which might not be in CTE.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES
(1234,     201308,       null,       null),
(1234,     201401,       null,       null),
(1234,     201408,       'ORANGE',     1),
(1234,     201501,       null,       null),
(1234,     201505,       null,       null),
(1234,     201508,       'OSCEOLA',    3),
(1234,     201601,       null,       null),
(5678,     201301,       null,       null),
(5678,     201305,       null,       null),
(5678,     201308,       'ST JOHNS',   3),
(5678,     201401,       null,       null),
(5678,     201405,       null,       null),
(5678,     201408,       null,       null),
(5678,     201501,       null,       null),
(5678,     201505,       'DUVAL',      4)
) as t(ID, TERM, COUNTY, [SEQUENCE])
)

SELECT  c.ID,
        c.TERM,
        COALESCE(c.COUNTY,p.COUNTY,p1.COUNTY) as COUNTY,
        c.[SEQUENCE]
FROM cte c
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 COUNTY
    FROM cte 
    WHERE ID = c.ID
        AND TERM < c.TERM
        AND COUNTY IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY TERM DESC) as p
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 COUNTY
    FROM cte 
    WHERE ID = c.ID
        AND [SEQUENCE] = 1
    ORDER BY TERM DESC) as p1
```

Will give you:

```
ID      TERM    COUNTY      SEQUENCE
1234    201308  ORANGE      NULL
1234    201401  ORANGE      NULL
1234    201408  ORANGE      1
1234    201501  ORANGE      NULL
1234    201505  ORANGE      NULL
1234    201508  OSCEOLA     3
1234    201601  OSCEOLA     NULL
5678    201301  NULL        NULL
5678    201305  NULL        NULL
5678    201308  ST JOHNS    3
5678    201401  ST JOHNS    NULL
5678    201405  ST JOHNS    NULL
5678    201408  ST JOHNS    NULL
5678    201501  ST JOHNS    NULL
5678    201505  DUVAL       4
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, gofr1, and this is very nearly perfect. The only minor hiccup is that the Sequence 1 value is not always 'CLAY'.  I am not familiar yet with the COALESCE function, so is there a way that the 'CLAY' in your code could be changed to "whatever the county is when the Sequence is 1"?

Comment: Coalesce returns first not null value from the list. Than I don't understand logic beyond your example. What about ID = 1234 and ORANGE county? There are sequence 1 but no CLAY, and ID 5678 where no sequence = 1 but there are CLAY.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. This is a subset of a substantial code, and one of the prior temp tables drawn upon has all address change dates and corresponding sequence #s. ID 5678 actually does have a Sequence 1 in the table being drawn from, but it was keyed prior  (201205, I believe... during the application phase) to the first Term the student attended which was 201301. The final overall table is only to reflect the dates the students attended.

Comment: In that case you better add samples of data before creating your output. The example I show is based only on output you provide

Comment: Since I am new to asking questions around here, how should I have phrased this in my initial post? I attempted with the "-ID 5678 should fill the preceding Terms with the Sequence 1 county as well (CLAY in this case) based on a previously joined table"

Comment: I really am sorry if I'm not being as clear as I should be (fighting off sleep-deprivation from a 3-week-old daughter at home). Rather than 'CLAY' in that code, should I replace it with a SELECT from the earlier temp table where the Sequence = 1?

Comment: I bet that CLAY is another COUNTY, so the way I have used here is to get next and last rows with not null county, and then coalesce them to get first not null value if COUNTY is null in a first table.

Comment: No need for apologizing, I suggest you to show the samples of tables you get data from and your query, that will be helpful to give you the right answer! :)

Comment: Ah! Forget! Congratulations! :)

Comment: Thanks again @gofr1! I have edited the initial post with the temp code for the student's address and sequence.

Answer (score 0):

See an example:

```
SELECT * into tbl_filltest FROM (
VALUES (1,Null),(2,Null),(3,5),(4,Null),(5,Null),(6,Null),(7,4),(8,Null),9,Null),(10,1)
 ) as t(c1,c2)
 GO
SELECT * FROM tbl_filltest
  GO
;WITH GoodValues as (SELECT * FROM tbl_filltest WHERE c2 is not null),
NullValues as (SELECT * FROM tbl_filltest WHERE c2 is null)
UPDATE n SET c2 = g1.c2 FROM GoodValues as g1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(c1) as Min_c1 FROM GoodValues as i WHERE g1.c1 > i.c1) as g2
INNER JOIN NullValues as n 
ON n.c1 > IsNull(g2.Min_c1,0) and n.c1 < g1.c1
GO
SELECT * FROM tbl_filltest
GO
```